# Download file from object storage through asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openstack-swift

I have files stored in an Openstack Swift container (object storage). I usually access them through an API, like this :

```
 _oApi.Swift.GetObject(containerName, fileName, outputStream);
```

Now, I have a web interface written in ASP NET Core 2.0, and I want users to be able to download files stored in the Swift container.

The following code has a drawback, the file is downloaded to my webserver first and only then, the download will start on the client side.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Download(string id)
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", filseSize);
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    _oApi.Swift.GetObject(containerName, fileName, Response.Body);
    return View();
}
```

How can I manage to stream the download directly to the client browser without caching the result on the webserver ?

PS: I am trying to work with a file that is 20mb or more as this code works well with small files.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the stream directly as the result instead of saving it to disk first.

Following example structure taken directly from [project repository on GitHub](https://github.com/cristipufu/SwiftClient)

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string id) {

    //...

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");

    var response = await _oApi.Swift.GetObject(containerName, fileName);

    if(response.IsSuccess) {
        return new FileStreamResult(response.Stream, "application/octet-stream");
    }

    return new NotFoundResult();
}
```

There was also this example which again was sampled based on your example

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string id) {
    var headObject = await _oApi.Swift.HeadObject(containerId, id);

    if (headObject.IsSuccess && headObject.ContentLength > 0) {
        var fileName = headObject.GetMeta("Filename");
        var contentType = headObject.GetMeta("Contenttype");

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");

        var stream = new BufferedHTTPStream((start, end) => {
            using (var response = _oApi.Swift.GetObjectRange(containerId, objectId, start, end).Result) {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                response.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms;
           }    
        }, () => headObject.ContentLength);

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType);
    }

    return new NotFoundResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried these samples before opening the issue. As the result of the request is stored on a stream on the controller, it first match the result in the server memory before returning the FileStreamResult.